# Unable to install VisualStudio Code in Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 with the latest patches and downloaded the VisualStudio Code setup from the official page but when I double click the .exe nothing happens, it does open a dialog and no error is displayed, just nothing happens, I tried running it as admin, restarting the machine multiple times, always the same result.

It just happens with this specific .exe, I tried with several other installations and it works fine.

Is there a way to see what could be blocking the installation?

Comment: Use Chocolatey to install visual studio code if you can't install it by clicking the exe file. See the folowing link: https://chocolatey.org/packages/vscode

Comment: That actually worked, if you add an answer I will mark it as solved

Comment: OK I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chocolatey to install visual studio code if you can't install it by clicking the exe file. See the folowing link:

[chocolatey.org/packages/vscode](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vscode)